# Connect to dev machine using IP address

Tags: networking, nodejs, development, websites

I'm working through tutorials using Angular and node. I am able to build and access my tutorial site on the `localhost:<port#>` and can also access them on the machine using `http://127.0.0.1:<port#>`. The next thing that I am trying to do is access the tutorial site I'm building using the IP address so that I can connect to it from other machines on my network. However, everything I have tried so far results in the browser throwing an error of unable to connect to the server. I looked up the IP address following the instructions on https://tecadmin.net/check-ip-address-ubuntu-18-04-desktop/.

What do I need to do so that I can use the IP address of the dev machine to access the site from other machines on the network?

```
localhost:<port#> - works fine on the machine
127.0.0.1:<port#> - works fine on the machine
IP address (https://10.x.y.z:<port#>) - unable to connect both from the same machine and other machines
```

Ping IP address from other machine gets a response

What I've tried so far:

```
ufw status: port shows allow
```

Comment: Which version of Linux/Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Usually this is the case of whatever softwrae you're using binding to localhost and NOT the IP address of the machine - how is your Angular app configured for port binding?